# Salesforce: SOAP Login from Salesforce TO Salesforce

Tags: web-services, soap, salesforce, sessionid

I implemented a batch job which makes a webservice call within the same salesforce instance, which then is supposed to send emails with a pdf attachment, 
since you cannot send pdf attachments directly from a batch job. My webservice call looks like this:

```
    public static void callOut(List ids){ 
        InvoiceAttachmentConnector.InvoiceAttachmentService ws = new InvoiceAttachmentConnector.InvoiceAttachmentService(); 
        ws.SessionHeader = new InvoiceAttachmentConnector.SessionHeader_element(); 
        ws.SessionHeader.sessionId = UserInfo.getSessionId(); 
        ws.handleInvoicePdfAttachment(ids); 
    }
```

However in batch jobs UserInfo.getSessionId() returns null, therefore i get a INVALID_SESSION_ID exception.

How can i log in to get a SessionId? So far I found no solution to login from salesforce to salesforce. If u can help I would appreciate it! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot get a session Id like this in batch apex as it runs under the system context and so has no specific user info for retrieval.

UPDATE:

You have the following options:

1. Try running the web services wsdl from your Salesforce org through the wsdl to apex generator in your org to generate some classes that may allow you to login. You are only allowed one web service request per execute call.
2. You could create a sites page that you make a HTTP get request to in your batch apex. This needs to retrieve the Ids of the items you want to send the PDFs for and a particular user to run as for you to use the System.runAs(user) method. You could pass these parameters in the HTTPRequest header or in a custom setting.

Note that neither of these solutions are ideal, you may want to reconsider why you are using Batch apex first of all and see whether you could reimplement it in a different way.

Comment: I know, this is why I want to find another way to get a Session Id. There got to be a way to call another salesforce webservice from apex code. And if u can call a sf webservice from apex, there has to be a possibility to log in and therefore obtain a session id.

Comment: I got it working last week with option 1. This link http://developer.force.com/cookbook/recipe/calling-salesforce-web-services-using-apex helped me a lot. The reason we need to use a batch job is, that we want to schedule a the job to automatically send invoices to customers.