# In Salesforce, how do I retrieve a valid SessionId from within a Batch Apex call?

Tags: session, service, salesforce, apex

I have a scenario where I am monitoring some data in Salesforce that is only available by screenscraping (eeek, I know, I know...but it is genuinely the only way of getting the data I need). Therefore I need to be able to get the contents of an HTML page by calling out to a custom REST service that exists in the same Salesforce org. This is all to get round the limitation of Batch Apex where "You cannot use the getContent and getContentAsPDF PageReference methods in a batch job."

I have seen on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9520877/salesforce-soap-login-from-salesforce-to-salesforce/9524529#9524529) a few suggestions but it ends with Phil indicating he had a solution but did not elaborate. All of the ones I can see would require you to set the username and password which I do not want to do as that would mean storing it somewhere and then having to update it each time it needs changing (which it would regularly). That kind of defeats the object of what I am trying to do.

I have also referenced this in a response [here](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=087300000006zM9AAI) to a delivered idea in the Ideas Exchange here.

Any bright ideas would be much appreciated!

Thanks
Jimski

Comment: If you don't want to store the username and password you could use OAuth to establish the session. Then you would only need to store the refresh token.

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks for responding. Unfortunately I'd have my package installed in multiple orgs, each with a different user account and connected app so I would need to store the username, password, secret etc... of these in a custom setting in each org (100+). Anytime the password changed I would need to update the custom setting which isn't very scalable.